# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck

Tags: java

I am trying to set values to a list of a class type.The values are getting fetched from database(MYSQL).The values are getting fetched properly but while setting to list there is possibly some errors are getting occured.

```
    public List<DataFetch> fetchdata(){
         List<DataFetch> ob=new ArrayList<DataFetch>();
         ResultSet rs = null;
          PreparedStatement pst = null;
          Connection con = getConnection();
          String stm = "Select * from client";
          try {   
             pst = con.prepareStatement(stm);
             pst.execute();
             rs = pst.getResultSet();
             int i=0;
             while(rs.next()){

                String clientname=rs.getString(1);
                String clientid=rs.getString(2);
               ob.set(i,new DataFetch(clientname,clientid));
               i++;
               /*  ob.setClientname(clientname);
                ob.setClientid(clientid);*/
             }
            // return ob;
          } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return (List<DataFetch>)ob;

    }
```

I am trying to print the values on console but getting this problem as follows:

```
Sep 05, 2015 11:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/DataTab] threw exception [Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:426)
    at UserData.fetchdata(UserData.java:49)
    at UserData.execData(UserData.java:29)
```

Kindly give a proper solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: On clicking submit navigation should be from home.xhtml to user.xhtml with some values getting printed on console...***Some extra parts i have included in the coding which are for other implementation.

Comment: The stackktrace clearely states an error. You can investigate way more what goes wrong I think. And try to break down your problem. Step by step.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because you are attempting to set an element in an empty List. In order to get rid of the error you have to replace this line (#49):

```
           `ob.set(i,new DataFetch(clientname,clientid));`
```

by this:

```
           `ob.add(new DataFetch(clientname,clientid));`
```

no `i` index, just add elements to the List.

Comment: The output in console i am getting is:hold
null..I have changed the code as above mentioned instruction.After setting values(inside while loop)to ob object(ob.add),the ob which is being returned contains items but their values for clientname and client id are null.It does mean there is some problem in setting values to object ob.please provide a proper solution.

Comment: ok got the point..There was some problem in constructor in DataFetch.

Comment: Plase accept my answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.